# Docker Container - Unable to access on the browser

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am new to docker and I've been trying to run pgadmin through docker. I ran the following command:

```
docker run -p 5555:80 --name pgadmin -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL="user@domain.com" -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD="***" dpage/pgadmin4
```

The container is currently running but I'm not able to access it through the browser (localhost:5555). It keeps loading gives me an error "Secure connection failed". Where am  I making a mistake?

PS:Please do let me know if any further information is needed to answer/understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate your issue if I use HTTPS with port 80.

At the time of writing this answer, the `dpage/pgadmin4` with the `latest` tag (which is the one you're using) exposes ports `80` and `443` - try using the other, secure one instead.

Your line should be: 
`docker run -p 5555:443 --name pgadmin -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL="user@domain.com" -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD="***" dpage/pgadmin4`

My guess is you're using something like HTTPS Everywhere and it forces you to use HTTPS on unsecured port, thus giving you this warning.